# Lock down OS to specific hardware device

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

I know everything is reversible.  But how could I lock down an instance of linux to a specific hardware device?  Possibly tying the filesystem to a specific serial number on the board for instance.

Comment: Please provide background/context and/or enumerate example attack(s) you are trying to prevent. i.e. are you trying to prevent someone from taking your desktop hard disk and using it on another machine? are you trying to distribute updates of a custom Linux OS and only have them run on select hardware? something else?

Comment: Yes we don't want a 3rd party to be able to easily copy/duplicate the image from the ssd and either distribute it or run it on another duplicate device.

Comment: Please also specify the target hardware. Is this a full-fledged a) Desktop/Laptop, b) Smartphone/Tablet, c) Raspberry PI or similar, d) something else?

Comment: Can your operating system require a connection to the internet on first boot to verify identity? If so, can it also require an internet connection on a set interval? Or is it an offline-only setup?

Comment: So to be perfectly clear, you're specifically asking for help in violating the GPL V3, which was revised from GPL V2 exactly to prevent vendors from preventing copying of the freely developed linux software they've built their systems with?

Comment: @deadlisting, Do you provide the target hardware to the client, or only the SSD? Do you have the ability to customize the hardware provided? Since this question is about hardware verification, it will require at least a little detail about the hardware. Your original question did not provide any details.

Comment: @JohnDeters, I would expect it to be more likely that he is distributing proprietary software that runs on the Linux operating system. Surely there is a way for him to do that without violating GPL? Deadlisting, Could you please clarify the reason for locking this down? Is it about software distribution, secret data, or something else?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Yes its a small arm device.  It's not an offline set up.  It does require internet for certain checks it does, ie wan check...etc.

Comment: @JohnDeters.  Technically we own the actual hardware.  The service/devices are rented as part of the service.

Comment: Yes actually we run specific software/configurations on top of this linux flavor.  So that's really what we are concerned about protecting.  Proprietary code and all that jazz.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution

1. On first boot, require authentication from the server. Have a Username which is stored on the device. The server provides a password associated with that username.
2. On later verification, send that password to the server.
3. The server sends back a new password which is stored. The client acknowledges receipt of the new password.
4. On later verification send the new password. If it doesn't work, tries the last known working password.
5. The server verifies the password is 'latest one that was acknowledged'.

   a) If it matches, the server proceeds at step 3. (new password for rotation)

   b) Otherwise, this is a copy, that is out of sync with the other instances of your device.

The client would have limited time use of these copies until the Server-verification catches the fraud. The client would have to make further modifications of you image to bypass this protection.

---

Hopefully someone else here knows how to check some hardware of your ARM device for a serial number, as that would provide a more immediate failure without waiting for an internet connection.

As you admit in your original post, these protections could be altered or removed by editing the contents of the SSD before duplicating.

---

The best solution would be to move a portion of the functionality to the cloud, so that an internet connection is required for *operation* instead of simply *verification*. Of course this is not always a possibility.

---

There may be specialized hardware out there which I am not familiar with which is

a) Difficult or impossible to copy.

b) Verifies the contents of the booting operating system

c) If OK, passes a decryption key needed to decrypt the application code before it can run.

---

There may be specialized hardware (again, not familiar with any) that takes this approach instead: Stores the encryption key in a self-destructable storage, so that when the frame of your device is opened, then the device will no longer be able to boot.

Also the device should be powered off at the same time to start the process of making the Memory irrecoverable.

If you are interested in any of these specialized hardware options then you should post a second question with specifics and maybe someone here will know if they exists and what they are called.

Edit: Many Android devices have something called Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and/or Secure Element (SE) which may be helpful search terms in the category of specialized hardware. See [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

Comment: It used the open embedded framework and is based on Angstrom.

Comment: I think your "simple solution" doesn't really lock the software down to one device. Instead, it ensures that only one copy (two at most) of the software is being used. But I could keep copying the software and moving it from PC to PC. I'm not sure that really solves the OP's question.

Comment: @Neil, I've improved the "simple solution" in regards to how it handles errors in exchanging revised passwords. The software would have to have either a time interval or counter to require re-validation with the server at a given interval, or else the software will not continue to function. So yes, a 'copy' may continue to function for a limited period of time, until it's up for re-validation. However, once the 2nd copy tries to validate, it will have a different password from the last one exchanged and the server will be able to alert Deadlisting of the fraud.

Comment: Validating on every boot would solve the problem more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

ARM have a [trusted computing implementation](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/) and some ARM licensees have their own solutions. This will allow you to encrypt your program and data both on disk and in memory, so no copying is possible without physically damaging the CPU.

The issues is trusted computing technology requires a lot of integration work (from bootloader to application), which may easily cost more than the value of your product.

If the ARM processor you use already have this feature built-in, using an Android-based OS can make the integration easier.

Comment: Unfortunately its an ARMv5